# Why is my ajax not passing in my parameter (always empty) via POST in Razor Page application?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I need this ajax call to run my onpost handler PassPart. It successfully calls it, but my parameter "searchedpart" is always empty. I've also tried passing the parameter directly in my url, like: "?handler=passPart" + "&searchedpart=" + searchedpart , but it's still empty. Lastly, I've tried using "Request.Form[SearchedPart]" in my method to pull the value in, also empty. I've tested that this element is not empty by adding an alert message to my js to confirm, and I see the value being found.

ps. I'm using an EmptyResult because I don't need anything posted back. I simply need it to run through my handler using the parameter.

```html
<form method="post">
    <input class="form-control" name="searchedpart" asp-for="PostData.SearchedPart" value="@Model.PostData.SearchedPart" id="searchedpart" />
    <button type="submit" id="searchpartbtn" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Find</button>
</form>
```

```js
document.getElementById('searchpartbtn').addEventListener('click', PassPart);
var searchedpart = document.getElementById('searchedpart').value;
function PassPart() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "?handler=passPart",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ searchedpart: searchedpart }),
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        }
    });
}
```

```cs
public ActionResult OnPostPassPart(string searchedpart = "")
{
    if (searchedpart != "") { 
        // Do Things
    }
    
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Hi @mstiver2018,any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1):

Because `searchedpart` is already a string type, there is no need to `JSON.stringify`.And you should write your `var searchedpart = document.getElementById('searchedpart').value;`code inside your `function`.

Just change your code as below:

```
  document.getElementById('searchpartbtn').addEventListener('click', PassPart);
    function PassPart() {
        var searchedpart = document.getElementById('searchedpart').value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?handler=PassPart",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "searchedpart": searchedpart },
           beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    }
        });
    }
```

In your background:

```
public ActionResult OnPostPassPart(string searchedpart)
{
//...
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I've tried this and still, searchedpart is null :( Does your HTML look exactly like mine? Maybe I have something in my input that shouldn't belong.

Comment: Update - Still no luck, I tried taking out the name, asp-for, and value tags (leaving only the id) and it still isn't passing.

Comment: I think I know your problem, you should write your `var searchedpart = document.getElementById('searchedpart').value;`code inside your `function`,I have updated my code, you can try it.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work. I don't think Post work that way, they need to be deserialized on the server side. Passing in parameters to a method will always be null unless it's a class.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following in my method to get this working:

```cs
string part = Request.Form["SearchedPart"];
```

Answer (score 0):

remove dataType: "json"
Add header token

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).